# Swagger | Access to folder XXXX is denied | XML Documentation

Tags: c#, xml, swagger

I am using Swagger for API documentation (My application is to be deployed in cloud) , It collects xml comments from xml documentation that is being enabled by right clicking project > go to properties  > Build tab > Enabling XML Documentation file check box.

The problem here is the default path will be "bin[AssemblyName].xml" I cant leave it to default path as it is not a best practice and checked in my code by changing the path to "helper[AssemblyName].xml".
Now when some team member gets the latest and tries to build it is throwing the following compile time error.

> "Access to folder XXXX is denied"

Which is fixed by un checking the Read Only check box in the folder properties.Though this fixes the issue I need a solution that works with out this solution.

Please suggest me some solution for the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the xml file exists in the bin folder. For me a folder was created. I deleted that folder, clean the code, rebuilt, built and voila the error was gone. The xml file showing all the comments was formed

Comment: This one saved me!